# Issues while trying to implement my own ThreadPool (Concept problems)

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency, synchronization, threadpool

I wanted to share my thoughts with you.
Consider you have to implement a Pool of Threads by yourself.

I thought of it to have some member field like `private static List<Thread>` of Threads to be my "pool".

I also have 2 methods:
a. Which assign thread from the pool.
b. Which return a thread to the pool.

**My questions are**:
1. How would you protect the `List` from being access by some threads at the same time:
I thought of declaring the two methods with `synchronize`, buy then realized that it's not good as I won't be able to do the following :
return a thread back to the pool while currently taking one from it.
I also thought of using a thread safe collection like Vector but seems like it has the same problem.

2.Do you think the Thread pool class should be a `Singleton`? and what part of the code do you think should be responsible to assign the single instance of it?

Comment: why should several threads access to `List<Thread>`?

Comment: Because If I want to get some of the threads from the pool
and in the same time another thread want to be released, they will be queued and not processed in the same time. lets say I already have some spare threads, then it will take the thread from collection- now we are blocked, and only after this will end we will be able to release one back to the pool

Comment: Imagine a multithreaded system with a lot of requests per second for threads

Comment: I think it's easier if you turn the problem around. Instead of handing out threads, accept objects implementing some interface, pick a thread and let it execute the objects designated method. Then you can easily catch exceptions that might have terminated the thread, create new threads, don't have to worry about getting the threads back etc.

Comment: Have a look at ThreadPoolExecutor. A thread pool is part of standard java now.

Comment: @opi: How can I see ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's implementation?

Comment: It's in the java src bundle.

Comment: @JavaSa. **Look at the interface first**. The implementation comes second, because the user will not see it. You use a `Queue` because of the operations it offers, not because inside there is a singleton. Same here.

Comment: You can read javadoc and just use the thread pool given by java. Its part of java sdk since 1.5 - you can get the java source code.

Comment: @JavaSa: You will only be locking for the tiny duration where you hand out a thread, and then for the tiny duration that the thread is handed back to the pool. Right? or are you thinking the lock will be held for longer?

Comment: If you do what @Erik suggests, you will probably find you don't even need a collection of the `Thread` objects themselves. The important thing is a queue of tasks; the threads then all read from that. The `Thread` objects actually aren't very important.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it is a fast operations: get, set, delete, add. So, if you wish it thread-saved, you need lock mechanism
2. I think, it depend on what you wish. in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.THREADING.THREADPOOL%29;k%28THREADPOOL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) is singleton
3. I think it is not 100% proper section for asking the question.

Comment: As for 1. I mentioned `synchronized` which provide some lock mechanism aside from Vector for example which is thread safe collection.  
As for 3. Where can I find the proper section for asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

The key to this question would depend on

whether you intend to actually re-use a thread for running multiple tasks and thus maintain a pool of threads without terminating them [A] or

whether you intend the pool only as a restriction to control the no of simultaneous tasks that can run at any given point and after each execution the thread would be killed and another one have to be created to take its place. [B]

[B] can be achieved quite easily by returning a new Thread object if the total no of outstanding job requests are below your system limits. Obviously the thread object should know how to decrement the common resource usage counter, before exiting. In this case you would not have to maintain a collection of threads but simply a reference to the common reference counting object (eg a semaphore) from all the threads.

[A] however, would require a class inherited from Thread which would not exit after it finishes executing a given task but would wait for the next task to be executed. Once this class is available, you can simply return the appropriate thread object reference to the caller and use a marker which will mark the thread as used or not in a thread safe way.

Here is one simple way to achieve this

```
ArrayList<MyThread>      pool = new ArrayList<MyThread>      (DEFAULT_POOL SIZE);
ArrayList<AtomicBoolean> used = new ArrayList<AtomicBoolean> (DEFAULT_POOL SIZE);
```

If you are returning pool[i] to the caller, mark it as being used, by performing

```
used[i].set(true).
```

Mark the same object as not being used (set(false) when the thread is returned to the pool. Obviously you would do this from synchronized allocate/deallocate methods. Since they are synchronized, the collection used to store the pooled threads needs not be synchronized and you can use any structure / collection, depending on the algorithm you use to determine which thread to give out next.

As an optimization, you could create the pool (and the individual threads) on the fly at the first request for a pooled thread - that way you need not initialize it until it is available. But you need to do it in a thread safe manner, details of which i wont go into.

As for question 2, it would be a good idea to make your pool class a singleton unless you want to create multiple pools, which would be dangerous if it went unchecked. It would also alleviate you from tracking how many such pools are instantiated if you are using a non static pool object.

As indicated you could save yourself the trouble by re-using the existing thread pool classes which handled the scenario A quite nicely for you :)